# Display font awesome icons in php if clause

Tags: php, html, if-statement, icons

I want to display font awesome icons depending on a condition of two php variable. For example

if($a > $b) display an arrow up icon else an arrow down icon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there's 2 ways to implement this, i don't know what the implementation is for. But in its most simple form it would look like this:

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 0;

if($a > $b){
 echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>';   
}
else{
 echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>';   
}
?>
```

You could also do it in 1 line this is called a [Ternary Expression](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-ternary-operator/), this is useually done with simple if statement, to make the code look cleaner.

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 0;

echo $a > $b ? '<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>'  : '<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>';
?>
```

As you can see the second option is cleaner, but it can get messy with longer expressions so beware.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a more descriptive version of @Kevin_Vink's response:

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 0;

$direction = $a > $b ? 'up' : 'down';

echo "<i class=\"fa-solid fa-arrow-{$direction}\"></i>";
```

Now `$direction` has the changing part in the FontAwesome class, which is inserted in the string using the `{$variable}` syntax inside a double-quoted string. The backslash before the internal double-quotes is for "escaping" them.

Note there is no closing `?>` PHP tag, is usually not needed (and most of the time, it's highly recommended not to have it).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating my anwer , I totally agree that the closing tag is unnecessary.